# "Main type not specified" with GWT and Eclipse Juno 4.2

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, eclipse-juno

After upgrading to Eclipse Juno 4.2 (through a fresh install) and installing GWT Plugin (3.0.0v201206271046-rel-r42) from http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2, I can't start my GWT application.

I configure the GWT nature of my project just like with Eclipse 3.7 but when I run my application, after selecting my entry point, the start fails with: "Main type not specified"

It appears gwt-dev.jar is not included. GWT referenced library are not added in my project. So I needed to reselect GWT 2.4 in my project configuration. Then, gwt-dev.jar is added correctly in the "Referenced Library" section. But I still get the same error at startup.

Any idea?

Comment: i'm experiencing the same issue.  where you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It has been workarounded by adding explicitely "com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode" in the "Main class" field on the "Main" tab in the run configuration

Comment: Quick hint for people here as this has nothing to do with a class called "Main" that I originally expected: 1) Select the App Engine Project 2) Go to the Run Menu 3) Select Run Configurations 4) Select your main .jsp startup file 5) Paste in "com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode" for the Main class value which has a "Search" button to the right.